# How to match all characters between [ ] and except ", "

Tags: regex, flutter

Hello I try to extract each group of data ( each data is separated by `,`  from a string like that

```
MyString=[XXXXXX:XX   XX   XX   XX, XXXXX:332.83, XXXXX:XXX-XX-XX XX:XX:XX, XXXX:0.0, XXXX:2, XXXX:0, XXXX:-256, counter_tipeee:5, XXXX:136935, XXXX:0, XXXX:XX XXX XXX, XXXX:0.5, XXXXX:true, XXXX:0.509375, XXX:0.0, XXXX:[2022-06-14 06:45:00], 2022-09-17 XXXXX:1]
```

With this regex, I can match all characters except `,`

```
([^,]*)
```

https://regex101.com/r/lCN2YK/1

But I search to mismatch `,`

The problem is if I remove space with \s, it removes space from certain data of my string. I search to extract all data that is not precisely coma+space `,` 
Another problem with my regex, it does not exclude the first `[` and the last `]` from my string. I can't exclude all `[  ]` because certain data have `[ ]`

I found this regex to exclude the first and last character ^.(.*).$ but don't know how to combine my two regex

https://regex101.com/r/CAsKHE/1

The output that I expect is

```
List<String> My_goal=  [

XXXXXX:XX   XX   XX   XX
XXXXX:332.83
XXXXX:XXX-XX-XX XX:XX:XX
XXXX:0.0, XXXX:2

....

2022-09-17,XXXXX:1
]
```

Comment: Does this work for you? https://regex101.com/r/g5euxw/1

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
(?<=(?<!: *)\[).*?(?=,)|(?<=, *(?=[^ \r\n]))(?:.*?(?=,)|[^,\r\n\[\]]+?(?=\])|[^,\r\n]+\](?= *\]))
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/l5Y5xr/1).

Comment: Sorry to bother, but I mismarked a specific case in the example. I have data like that 2022-09-17,XXXXX:1 but with this regex the coma is detected. I search to not exclude coma if there is no space after him. Hope it's possible to do